# XSLT 3.0 Unable to get accumulator map value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have aggregated 2 xml data sources (Report data and Qualification Equivalence Rules) into a root node and used XSLT 3.0 accumulator & map function. I am unable to get the accumulator map value returned in the output. The 'QER' and 'QCert' values are coming out blank. Not sure if it is a template issue. Any help is highly appreciated.

INPUT XML ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <Qualifications>
        <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
                                           xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Reference>
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f67d472cae9501e32555411f04061766</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Qualification_Equivalence_Rule">QUALIFICATION_EQUIVALENCE_RULE-6-411</wd:ID>
            </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Reference>
            <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data>
                <wd:ID>QUALIFICATION_EQUIVALENCE_RULE-6-411</wd:ID>
                <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Inactive>0</wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Inactive>
                <wd:Job_Profile_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1117412e168001250ea7f14c41031293</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">51227</wd:ID>
                </wd:Job_Profile_Reference>
                <wd:Condition_Rule_Data>
                    <wd:Condition_Rule_ID>CONDITION_RULE-6-1097</wd:Condition_Rule_ID>
                    <wd:Rule_Description>51227</wd:Rule_Description>
                    <wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                        <wd:Order>a</wd:Order>
                        <wd:And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da4e1c34446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="And_Or_Operator_Name">And</wd:ID>
                        </wd:And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                        <wd:Relational_Operator_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">d5227566446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Relational_Operator_Name">any in the selection list</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Relational_Operator_Reference>
                        <wd:Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da59516c446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Condition_Entry_Option_Name">Value specified in this filter</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                        <wd:Source_External_Field_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">2da3447d0426100005f7c3e752840110</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Source_External_Field_Reference>
                        <wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f67d472cae95016d99f7feeb7a05f065</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Certification_ID">BCBA</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                    </wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                </wd:Condition_Rule_Data>
            </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data>
        </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule>
        <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
            xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Reference>
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f67d472cae95013dc439f7fc0306ba60</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Qualification_Equivalence_Rule">QUALIFICATION_EQUIVALENCE_RULE-6-2</wd:ID>
            </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Reference>
            <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data>
                <wd:ID>QUALIFICATION_EQUIVALENCE_RULE-6-2</wd:ID>
                <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Inactive>0</wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Inactive>
                <wd:Job_Profile_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1117412e168001d24f02c14c41030c92</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">48082</wd:ID>
                </wd:Job_Profile_Reference>
                <wd:Condition_Rule_Data>
                    <wd:Condition_Rule_ID>CONDITION_RULE-6-f67d472cae9501a42c52f7fc0306bb60</wd:Condition_Rule_ID>
                    <wd:Rule_Description>48082</wd:Rule_Description>
                    <wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                        <wd:Order>a</wd:Order>
                        <wd:And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da4e1c34446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="And_Or_Operator_Name">And</wd:ID>
                        </wd:And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                        <wd:Relational_Operator_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">d5227566446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Relational_Operator_Name">any in the selection list</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Relational_Operator_Reference>
                        <wd:Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da59516c446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Condition_Entry_Option_Name">Value specified in this filter</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                        <wd:Source_External_Field_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">2da3447d0426100005f7c3e752840110</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Source_External_Field_Reference>
                        <wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f67d472cae9501f92ccd15ec7a053966</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Certification_ID">CBAP</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                        <wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f67d472cae9501f92ccd15ec7a053967</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Certification_ID">PMI-PBA</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                    </wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                </wd:Condition_Rule_Data>
            </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data>
        </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule>
    </Qualifications>
    <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Worker_Certs">
        <wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:Worker wd:Descriptor="Tom Hanks">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b0d4df2a9611018f7b47c85f110d8230</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">770077</wd:ID>
            </wd:Worker>
            <wd:Job_Profile wd:Descriptor="48082 - Business Analyst">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1117412e168001d24f02c14c41030c92</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">48082</wd:ID>
            </wd:Job_Profile>
            <wd:Certification wd:Descriptor="CBAP - Certified Business Analyst Professional">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b0d4df2a96110179f7d634a5310de855</wd:ID>
            </wd:Certification>
            <wd:Certification_-_Selected_group>
                <wd:referenceID>CBAP</wd:referenceID>
            </wd:Certification_-_Selected_group>
            <wd:Cert_Number>2100</wd:Cert_Number>
            <wd:Issuer>IIBA</wd:Issuer>
            <wd:Expiration_Date>2023-12-31-08:00</wd:Expiration_Date>
        </wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:Worker wd:Descriptor="Russel Crowe">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b0d4df2a961101bdb3b6ae7b120dd829</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">77088</wd:ID>
            </wd:Worker>
            <wd:Job_Profile wd:Descriptor="51227 - Board Certified Behav Analyst">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1117412e168001250ea7f14c41031293</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">51227</wd:ID>
            </wd:Job_Profile>
            <wd:Certification wd:Descriptor="Board Certified Behavior Analyst - Behavior Analyst Certification Board">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e27b2aff960c01a0b7f176c5b201122a</wd:ID>
            </wd:Certification>
            <wd:Certification_-_Selected_group>
                <wd:referenceID>BCBA</wd:referenceID>
            </wd:Certification_-_Selected_group>
            <wd:Cert_Number>1/11/8595</wd:Cert_Number>
            <wd:Issuer>Behavior Analyst Certification Board</wd:Issuer>
            <wd:Expiration_Date>2023-05-31-07:00</wd:Expiration_Date>
        </wd:Report_Entry>      
    </wd:Report_Data>
</root>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" 
    xmlns:wd2="urn:com.workday.report/Worker_Certs" 
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
        
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Declare Accumulator to store the Job Profile ID from Web Service, this will be used to lookup Cert ID from the Web Service -->
    <xsl:accumulator name="qjp.id" streamable="yes" as="xs:string" initial-value="''">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="wd:Job_Profile_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Job_Profile_ID']/text()" select="."/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    <!-- Declare Accumulator with map to lookup CertID from Web Service -->
    <xsl:accumulator name="map.cert" as="map(xs:string,xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="wd:Target_Instance_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Certification_ID']/text()">
            <xsl:sequence select="map:put($value, accumulator-after('qjp.id'), xs:string(.))"/>
        </xsl:accumulator-rule>
    </xsl:accumulator> 

    <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="#all"/>
    <xsl:mode streamable="no" name="in-memory"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>            
        </root>
    </xsl:template>       

    <xsl:template match="wd2:Report_Entry">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of()" mode="in-memory"/>
    </xsl:template>

 <!--  
    <xsl:template match="wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of()" mode="in-memory"/>
    </xsl:template>
-->

    <xsl:template match="wd2:Report_Entry" mode="in-memory">
        
        <xsl:variable name="vmap.cert" select="accumulator-after('map.cert')"/>

        <xsl:variable name="v.empl_id" select="wd2:Worker/wd2:ID[@wd2:type='Employee_ID']" />
        <xsl:variable name="v.jp_id" select="wd2:Job_Profile/wd2:ID[@wd2:type='Job_Profile_ID']" />
        <xsl:variable name="v.cert_id" select="wd2:Cert_Number"/>
        <xsl:variable name="v.Cref" select="wd2:Certification_-_Selected_group/wd2:referenceID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="v.exp_dt" select="substring(wd2:Expiration_Date,1,10)"/>

        <Worker_Cert>
            
            <Emp_ID><xsl:value-of select="$v.empl_id"/></Emp_ID>
            <Job_Profile_ID><xsl:value-of select="$v.jp_id"/></Job_Profile_ID>
            <Cref><xsl:value-of select="$v.Cref"/></Cref>
            <Cert_Number><xsl:value-of select="$v.cert_id"/></Cert_Number>
            <Expiration_Dt><xsl:value-of select="$v.exp_dt"/></Expiration_Dt>
            <QER>
                <QCert><xsl:value-of select="$vmap.cert ($v.jp_id)"/></QCert>            
            </QER>    
        </Worker_Cert>

    </xsl:template>
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Final Expected Output ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
      xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
      xmlns:wd2="urn:com.workday.report/Worker_Certs">
   <Worker_Cert>
      <Emp_ID>770077</Emp_ID>
      <Job_Profile_ID>48082</Job_Profile_ID>
      <Cref>CBAP</Cref>
      <Cert_Number>2100</Cert_Number>
      <Expiration_Dt>2023-12-31</Expiration_Dt>
      <QCert>CBAP</QCert>
   </Worker_Cert>
   <Worker_Cert>
      <Emp_ID>770088</Emp_ID>
      <Job_Profile_ID>51227</Job_Profile_ID>
      <Cref>BCBA</Cref>
      <Cert_Number>2100</Cert_Number>
      <Expiration_Dt>2023-05-31</Expiration_Dt>
      <QCert>BCBA</QCert>
   </Worker_Cert>
</root>
```

Comment: You construct that second accumulator with the map on matches to `wd:Target_Instance_Reference` which seems to only follow the `wd2:Report_Entry` you process in your template so I am not sure in what way you expect to have the map with any values present, at least with streaming, while parsing/processing `wd2:Report_Entry`, where the `wd:Target_Instance_Reference` have not been parsed/processed at all.

Comment: If you had the `Qualifications` first and then the `wd:Report_Data`, your data from the accumulators would populate the elements `QER` and `QCert`.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you very much for reviewing my issue and for providing your comments. I am trying to follow your inputs, however I think I am not fully understanding what you are indicating when you say 'wd:Target_Instance_Reference needs to be parsed/processed at all'. Do you mean how am I linking wd:Target_Instance_Reference under wd2:Report_Entry? Do I need to put the 'wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data' in-memory as well?

Comment: Oh I follow your comments now, so my aggregation should have qualifications xml before report data, thanks I can definitely try that.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for pointing out the issue in my input xml. I rearranged it to have qualifications go before report and that got me to accumulator map value. However I am  facing another issue, I have multiple node values of wd:Target_Instance_Reference which I would like to display under QER tag for the matching job profile. I am only able to see 1 node value currently. How can I ensure all wd:Target_Instance_Reference node values for matching job profile are displayed under QER tag.

Comment: I am not able to react to additional or new questions raised in a comment, either edit your question with all the current details of the problem and describe the result you want or close this question and raise a new one.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited the input xml (qualifications xml) to reflect my latest question/issue. It has 2 nodes of wd:Target_Instance_Reference with values as 'CBAP' and 'PMI-PBA'. I would like both these values to show under QER tag because they are for same job profile '48082' in qualification xml which matches to the job profile value in report xml.

Comment: Your current code for me outputs an empty `<QCert></QCert>` element. If I swap the data in the input, as said before, and put the `Qualifications` element before the `wd:Report_Data`, the element gets a value, namely `<QCert>PMI-PBA</QCert>`, without changing any of the XSLT. It is not clear to me, therefore, whether you take into account that, with streaming, your accumulator values collected for elements inside of the `Qualifications` element are not available while your code processes `wd:Report_Data` elements located before the `Qualifications`.

Comment: As for getting more than one value, you declare the second accumulator as a map but your key for the map seems to be the value you collect before and only once, so that way, if you have more than one `wd:ID wd:type="Certification_ID"`, you of course overwrite the value in the map. It is not clear whether you have several `Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data` or only one but in the context of on it seems you want to store a sequence of values in the map, not a single value.

Comment: Hi Martin, I updated the code to have qualifications before report and I am getting exact same result like yours. I get one QCert node with value PMI-PBA. However, if you look at the input xml, there are 2 nodes with CBAP and PMI-PBA. So I am expecting both values to show in the output.

Comment: Hi Martin, yes there are cases where there will be multiple wd:Target_Instance_Reference nodes under <wd:Condition_Item_Data> which ultimately comes under   <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data>. Is there a way the accumulator can be configured to handle this scenario? so in our example, I should get an output of CBAP and PMI-PBA as separate QCert node values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store more than one value related to a key in your map change

```
<xsl:accumulator name="map.cert" as="map(xs:string,xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="wd:Target_Instance_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Certification_ID']/text()">
        <xsl:sequence select="map:put($value, accumulator-after('qjp.id'), xs:string(.))"/>
    </xsl:accumulator-rule>
</xsl:accumulator>
```

to

```
<xsl:accumulator name="map.cert" as="map(xs:string,xs:string+)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="wd:Target_Instance_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Certification_ID']/text()">
        <xsl:sequence select="if (map:contains($value, accumulator-after('qjp.id'))) then map:put($value, accumulator-after('qjp.id'), (map:get($value, accumulator-after('qjp.id')), string()) else map:put($value, accumulator-after('qjp.id'), string())"/>
    </xsl:accumulator-rule>
</xsl:accumulator>
```

I am still not sure how you want to use that accumulator with the order of data in your sample in the question but the suggestion above at least should help to store a sequence of values.

Comment: Hi Martin,Thanks for sharing an alternative. I think this results in a concatenated value of all nodes which may not help. Let me clarify what I intended to do - I was trying to get all matching job profile and corresponding certification node values from qualification xml that matched the job profile values in report xml. After getting that, I finally intended to only display those certifications from the qualification xml that are available on the report xml for that worker for the matched job profile. I updated input xml & added a final expected output section to explain my requirement.

Comment: @user13468980, it is very hard to follow all your edits, and perhaps cut your samples to show the essential (and perhaps even) simplified basic data. Your current input sample now has three `wd:Report_Entry` elements you process all with a matching template, I fail to see how you would end up with only two `Worker_Cert` in the output. I realize the accumulator suggestion is not what you want but in the end you will need to store the values you know you need, I am afraid so far I have not understood which ones in which relationship those values are.

Comment: Hi Martin, My bad for the input xml confusion. I mistakenly copied over extra node in the report xml section. I have fixed it now. Hopefully that should make sense. please let me know. The alternative you provided made me think that maybe I could still use the 'map:contains' function to accomplish the final expected output.

Comment: Hi Martin, in order to get the desired output can I use the 'map:contains' function in such a way that it compares if the match value from accumulator map is equal to the value in wd2: wd:referenceID, only then write that value using map:put?

Comment: When I search your current sample for `wd:referenceID`, I find those values inside of the `wd:Report_Entry` element. When your build the map of the accumulator, you are processing different elements so I don't understand how you expect to access `wd:referenceID` while constructing the map.

Comment: Thanks for your response Martin, my understanding was that I could not fetch the wd:ReferenceID in the accumulator but I thought maybe there is a way to handle this that I am not aware of considering my limited knowledge about the subject. I went for accumulators and map function assuming this would be easier to handle but I am not able use it. Is there an alternative way to handle this?

Comment: @user13468980, well, the primary question is of course whether you do need to use streaming or not. Do you use streaming and is the data so large that normal processing without streaming doesn't work (where you could use keys or normal XPath navigation)?

Comment: Hi Martin, at this point the input XML shows 251024 number of rows data. It holds all emps info but I will have to filter it for only those emps whose certs are expiring in next 30 days. So streaming does not seem to be a requirement. I reposted question with input xml & output expected format. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72703800/how-to-display-a-node-value-only-when-it-exists-in-another-node