# How to display a node value only when it exists in another node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0, xslt-grouping

I have a combined xml of 2 separate data sources - qualifications and report data. The report data xml section has job profile and certification ref ID. The qualifications xml section has job profile and multiple certification ref IDs associated with it. I am trying to generate a final output xml that should display the job profile ID and the certification ref ID from the report data xml section only when there is a matching job profile and certification ref ID in qualifications XML section. I tried using the xslt 3.0 accumulator - map function but haven't been able to use it as my knowledge is very basic.

Here are the details to the input file and the expected output file. Would appreciate any help around this issue.

INPUT FILE ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <Qualifications>
        <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
                                           xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Reference>
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">c3b39ac5d3e2014bb44feeb7a60d7d04</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Qualification_Equivalence_Rule">QUALIFICATION_EQUIVALENCE_RULE-3-563</wd:ID>
            </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Reference>
            <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data>
                <wd:ID>QUALIFICATION_EQUIVALENCE_RULE-3-563</wd:ID>
                <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Inactive>0</wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Inactive>
                <wd:Job_Profile_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1117412e16800106d9c1c14c41031092</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">48084</wd:ID>
                </wd:Job_Profile_Reference>
                <wd:Condition_Rule_Data>
                    <wd:Condition_Rule_ID>CONDITION_RULE-3-1468</wd:Condition_Rule_ID>
                    <wd:Rule_Description>48084</wd:Rule_Description>
                    <wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                        <wd:Order>a</wd:Order>
                        <wd:And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da4e1c34446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="And_Or_Operator_Name">And</wd:ID>
                        </wd:And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                        <wd:Relational_Operator_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">d5227566446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Relational_Operator_Name">any in the selection list</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Relational_Operator_Reference>
                        <wd:Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da59516c446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Condition_Entry_Option_Name">Value specified in this filter</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                        <wd:Source_External_Field_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">2da3447d0426100005f7c3e752840110</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Source_External_Field_Reference>
                        <wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f67d472cae95013c50ff3dec7a05bf66</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Certification_ID">REEGT</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                    </wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                </wd:Condition_Rule_Data>
            </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data>
        </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule>    
        <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
            xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Reference>
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f67d472cae950122e67fdf1a04066965</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Qualification_Equivalence_Rule">QUALIFICATION_EQUIVALENCE_RULE-6-357</wd:ID>
            </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Reference>
            <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data>
                <wd:ID>QUALIFICATION_EQUIVALENCE_RULE-6-357</wd:ID>
                <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Inactive>0</wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Inactive>
                <wd:Job_Profile_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1117412e1680011e3e797b4c4103a890</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">47063</wd:ID>
                </wd:Job_Profile_Reference>
                <wd:Condition_Rule_Data>
                    <wd:Condition_Rule_ID>CONDITION_RULE-6-1043</wd:Condition_Rule_ID>
                    <wd:Rule_Description>47063</wd:Rule_Description>
                    <wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                        <wd:Order>a</wd:Order>
                        <wd:And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da4e1c34446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="And_Or_Operator_Name">And</wd:ID>
                        </wd:And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                        <wd:Relational_Operator_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">d5227566446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Relational_Operator_Name">any in the selection list</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Relational_Operator_Reference>
                        <wd:Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da59516c446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Condition_Entry_Option_Name">Value specified in this filter</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                        <wd:Source_External_Field_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">2da3447d0426100005f7c3e752840110</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Source_External_Field_Reference>
                        <wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f67d472cae9501225db826ec7a057066</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Certification_ID">SLP</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                    </wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                    <wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                        <wd:Order>b</wd:Order>
                        <wd:And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da4e1c34446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="And_Or_Operator_Name">And</wd:ID>
                        </wd:And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                        <wd:Relational_Operator_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">d5227566446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Relational_Operator_Name">any in the selection list</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Relational_Operator_Reference>
                        <wd:Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da59516c446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Condition_Entry_Option_Name">Value specified in this filter</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                        <wd:Source_External_Field_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">2da3447d0426100005f7c3e752840110</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Source_External_Field_Reference>
                        <wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f67d472cae95015969f6ffeb7a05f465</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Certification_ID">CCC-SLP</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                    </wd:Condition_Item_Data>                   
                </wd:Condition_Rule_Data>
            </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data>
        </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule>    
        <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
            xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Reference>
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f67d472cae9501e32555411f04061766</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Qualification_Equivalence_Rule">QUALIFICATION_EQUIVALENCE_RULE-6-411</wd:ID>
            </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Reference>
            <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data>
                <wd:ID>QUALIFICATION_EQUIVALENCE_RULE-6-411</wd:ID>
                <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Inactive>0</wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Inactive>
                <wd:Job_Profile_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1117412e168001250ea7f14c41031293</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">51227</wd:ID>
                </wd:Job_Profile_Reference>
                <wd:Condition_Rule_Data>
                    <wd:Condition_Rule_ID>CONDITION_RULE-6-1097</wd:Condition_Rule_ID>
                    <wd:Rule_Description>51227</wd:Rule_Description>
                    <wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                        <wd:Order>a</wd:Order>
                        <wd:And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da4e1c34446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="And_Or_Operator_Name">And</wd:ID>
                        </wd:And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                        <wd:Relational_Operator_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">d5227566446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Relational_Operator_Name">any in the selection list</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Relational_Operator_Reference>
                        <wd:Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da59516c446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Condition_Entry_Option_Name">Value specified in this filter</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                        <wd:Source_External_Field_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">2da3447d0426100005f7c3e752840110</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Source_External_Field_Reference>
                        <wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f67d472cae95016d99f7feeb7a05f065</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Certification_ID">BCBA</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                    </wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                </wd:Condition_Rule_Data>
            </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data>
        </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule>
        <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
            xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Reference>
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f67d472cae95013dc439f7fc0306ba60</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Qualification_Equivalence_Rule">QUALIFICATION_EQUIVALENCE_RULE-6-2</wd:ID>
            </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Reference>
            <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data>
                <wd:ID>QUALIFICATION_EQUIVALENCE_RULE-6-2</wd:ID>
                <wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Inactive>0</wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Inactive>
                <wd:Job_Profile_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1117412e168001d24f02c14c41030c92</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">48082</wd:ID>
                </wd:Job_Profile_Reference>
                <wd:Condition_Rule_Data>
                    <wd:Condition_Rule_ID>CONDITION_RULE-6-f67d472cae9501a42c52f7fc0306bb60</wd:Condition_Rule_ID>
                    <wd:Rule_Description>48082</wd:Rule_Description>
                    <wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                        <wd:Order>a</wd:Order>
                        <wd:And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da4e1c34446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="And_Or_Operator_Name">And</wd:ID>
                        </wd:And_Or_Operator_Reference>
                        <wd:Relational_Operator_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">d5227566446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Relational_Operator_Name">any in the selection list</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Relational_Operator_Reference>
                        <wd:Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">da59516c446c11de98360015c5e6daf6</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Condition_Entry_Option_Name">Value specified in this filter</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Condition_Entry_Option_Reference>
                        <wd:Source_External_Field_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">2da3447d0426100005f7c3e752840110</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Source_External_Field_Reference>
                        <wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f67d472cae9501f92ccd15ec7a053966</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Certification_ID">CBAP</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                        <wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f67d472cae9501f92ccd15ec7a053967</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Certification_ID">PMI-PBA</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Target_Instance_Reference>
                    </wd:Condition_Item_Data>
                </wd:Condition_Rule_Data>
            </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data>
        </wd:Qualification_Equivalence_Rule>
    </Qualifications>
    <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Worker_Certs">
        <wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:Worker wd:Descriptor="Tom Hanks">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b0d4df2a9611018f7b47c85f110d8230</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">770077</wd:ID>
            </wd:Worker>
            <wd:Job_Profile wd:Descriptor="48082 - Business Analyst">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1117412e168001d24f02c14c41030c92</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">48082</wd:ID>
            </wd:Job_Profile>
            <wd:Certification wd:Descriptor="CBAP - Certified Business Analyst Professional">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b0d4df2a96110179f7d634a5310de855</wd:ID>
            </wd:Certification>
            <wd:Certification_-_Selected_group>
                <wd:referenceID>CBAP</wd:referenceID>
            </wd:Certification_-_Selected_group>
            <wd:Cert_Number>2100</wd:Cert_Number>
            <wd:Issuer>IIBA</wd:Issuer>
            <wd:Expiration_Date>2023-12-31-08:00</wd:Expiration_Date>
        </wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:Worker wd:Descriptor="Russel Crowe">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b0d4df2a961101bdb3b6ae7b120dd829</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">77088</wd:ID>
            </wd:Worker>
            <wd:Job_Profile wd:Descriptor="51227 - Board Certified Behav Analyst">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1117412e168001250ea7f14c41031293</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">51227</wd:ID>
            </wd:Job_Profile>
            <wd:Certification wd:Descriptor="Board Certified Behavior Analyst - Behavior Analyst Certification Board">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e27b2aff960c01a0b7f176c5b201122a</wd:ID>
            </wd:Certification>
            <wd:Certification_-_Selected_group>
                <wd:referenceID>BCBA</wd:referenceID>
            </wd:Certification_-_Selected_group>
            <wd:Cert_Number>1/11/8595</wd:Cert_Number>
            <wd:Issuer>Behavior Analyst Certification Board</wd:Issuer>
            <wd:Expiration_Date>2023-05-31-07:00</wd:Expiration_Date>
        </wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:Worker wd:Descriptor="Mel Gibson">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b0d4df2a961101bdb3b6ae7b120dd830</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">77099</wd:ID>
            </wd:Worker>
            <wd:Job_Profile wd:Descriptor="47063 - Manager Speech / Language Pathology">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1117412e168001250ea7f14c41031293</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">47063</wd:ID>
            </wd:Job_Profile>
            <wd:Certification wd:Descriptor="Board Certified Behavior Analyst - Behavior Analyst Certification Board">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e27b2aff960c01a0b7f176c5b201122a</wd:ID>
            </wd:Certification>
            <wd:Certification_-_Selected_group>
                <wd:referenceID>SLP</wd:referenceID>
            </wd:Certification_-_Selected_group>
            <wd:Cert_Number>112233</wd:Cert_Number>
            <wd:Issuer>PSLB</wd:Issuer>
            <wd:Expiration_Date>20232-12-31-08:00</wd:Expiration_Date>
        </wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:Worker wd:Descriptor="Robert Downey Jr.">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">b0d4df2a961101bdb3b6ae7b120dd830</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_ID">88000</wd:ID>
            </wd:Worker>
            <wd:Job_Profile wd:Descriptor="47063 - Manager Speech / Language Pathology">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1117412e168001250ea7f14c41031293</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Profile_ID">48084</wd:ID>
            </wd:Job_Profile>
            <wd:Certification wd:Descriptor="Board Certified Behavior Analyst - Behavior Analyst Certification Board">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e27b2aff960c01a0b7f176c5b201122a</wd:ID>
            </wd:Certification>
            <wd:Certification_-_Selected_group>
                <wd:referenceID>EEG</wd:referenceID>
            </wd:Certification_-_Selected_group>
            <wd:Cert_Number>112244</wd:Cert_Number>
            <wd:Issuer>EEG</wd:Issuer>
            <wd:Expiration_Date>20232-11-30-08:00</wd:Expiration_Date>
        </wd:Report_Entry>      
    </wd:Report_Data>
</root>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT FILE ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
      xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
      xmlns:wd2="urn:com.workday.report/Worker_Certs">
   <Worker_Cert>
      <Emp_ID>770077</Emp_ID>
      <Job_Profile_ID>48082</Job_Profile_ID>
      <Cref>CBAP</Cref>
      <Cert_Number>2100</Cert_Number>
      <Expiration_Dt>2023-12-31</Expiration_Dt>
      <QCert>CBAP</QCert>
   </Worker_Cert>
   <Worker_Cert>
      <Emp_ID>77088</Emp_ID>
      <Job_Profile_ID>51227</Job_Profile_ID>
      <Cref>BCBA</Cref>
      <Cert_Number>1/11/8595</Cert_Number>
      <Expiration_Dt>2023-05-31</Expiration_Dt>
      <QCert>BCBA</QCert>
   </Worker_Cert>
   <Worker_Cert>
      <Emp_ID>77099</Emp_ID>
      <Job_Profile_ID>47063</Job_Profile_ID>
      <Cref>SLP</Cref>
      <Cert_Number>112233</Cert_Number>
      <Expiration_Dt>20232-12-3</Expiration_Dt>
      <QCert>SLP</QCert>
   </Worker_Cert>
</root>
```

Comment: At least with traditional XSLT 2/3 a cross-reference lookup with a composite key should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key based approach is e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/root" xpath-default-namespace="">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="ref" 
           match="Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data/Condition_Rule_Data/Condition_Item_Data/Target_Instance_Reference/ID[@wd:type = 'Certification_ID']" 
           use="ancestor::Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data/Job_Profile_Reference/ID[@wd:type = 'Job_Profile_ID'], ." 
           composite="yes"/>

  <xsl:template xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday.report/Worker_Certs" 
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Worker_Certs" 
                match="Report_Entry[key('ref', (Job_Profile/ID[@wd:type = 'Job_Profile_ID'], Certification_-_Selected_group/referenceID))]">
    <Worker_Cert>
      <Emp_ID>{Worker/ID[@wd:type = 'Employee_ID']}</Emp_ID>
      <Job_Profile_ID>{Job_Profile/ID[@wd:type = 'Job_Profile_ID']}</Job_Profile_ID>
      <Cref>{key('ref', (Job_Profile/ID[@wd:type = 'Job_Profile_ID'], Certification_-_Selected_group/referenceID))}</Cref>
    </Worker_Cert>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Streaming should do with e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="#all" streamable="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:accumulator name="jpid" as="xs:string?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data" select="()"/>
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data/Job_Profile_Reference/ID[@wd:type = 'Job_Profile_ID']/text()" select="string()"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    <xsl:accumulator name="certs" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="Qualification_Equivalence_Rule_Data/Condition_Rule_Data/Condition_Item_Data/Target_Instance_Reference/ID[@wd:type = 'Certification_ID']/text()"
          select="let $jpid := accumulator-before('jpid'),
                      $key := $jpid || '|' || string()
                  return map:put($value, $key, string())"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    <xsl:template match="/root" xpath-default-namespace="">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="Report_Entry" xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday.report/Worker_Certs">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of()" mode="grounded"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:mode name="grounded" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
   
    <xsl:template mode="grounded"
        xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday.report/Worker_Certs" 
        xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Worker_Certs" 
        match="Report_Entry[map:contains(accumulator-before('certs'), Job_Profile/ID[@wd:type = 'Job_Profile_ID'] || '|' || Certification_-_Selected_group/referenceID)]">
        <Worker_Cert>
            <Emp_ID>{Worker/ID[@wd:type = 'Employee_ID']}</Emp_ID>
            <Job_Profile_ID>{Job_Profile/ID[@wd:type = 'Job_Profile_ID']}</Job_Profile_ID>
            <Cref>{accumulator-before('certs')(Job_Profile/ID[@wd:type = 'Job_Profile_ID'] || '|' || Certification_-_Selected_group/referenceID)}</Cref>
        </Worker_Cert>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you very much for providing both approach solutions. I am able to get the expected results with both, however with the streaming (accumulator) option, I see that the output returns emp data for unmatched rows too. This does not occur with the key approach. I updated the input xml with additional data so you could verify this case when you run the streaming vs key solution. Using the key approach, do we need to use "xpath-default-namespace" or can we still define wd and wd2 as separate namespaces and continue them in the program?

Comment: @user13468980, right, there was a declaration of e.g. `<xsl:mode name="grounded" on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>` missing from the second stylesheet, not noted due to the lack of test data, now fixed.

Comment: Hi Martin,Thanks. that fixed it! I notice that the output file is giving multiple root nodes of <Worker_Certs>, how do we embed that into single root node - maybe like <All_Certs>?

Comment: @user13468980, in both XSLT samples I copy the "root" sample root element from your input sample shown with e.g. `<xsl:template match="/root"><xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">..`, for those samples that should work to ensure the result has a root element. If you have different input with a different root element (or simply a different namespace than the non namespace of your shown sample) then you need to change/adapt that template to match on your input. You can of course do e.g. `<xsl:template match="/*">` for instance, to match any root element.

Comment: Hi Martin, I tried re-running both XSLT samples on the input xml provided above but I'm not seeing the <root></root> node in the output. Can you please confirm again. That's the same node that I am trying to use in my program.

Comment: @user13468980, I have changed the template from having `<xsl:template match="/root">` to using `<xsl:template match="/root" xpath-default-namespace="">`. Too many namespaces and perhaps indeed a case where using prefixes instead of `xpath-default-namespace` is more suitable.

Comment: Thanks Martin for all the help. I agree, trying that alternative too to keep prefixes instead.